# how can fix refresh problem in react router

Tags: reactjs, react-router

i have a strange problem in my react application , i have two phase in my app , first is normal users that is web page and the other is dashboard for admins . in my dashboard when i refresh the page where ever i been the page redirects to /dashboard , for example i'm in /dashboard/cartable/requests then i refresh the page and page go to /dashboard page.
my codes is in below :
my app.js :

```js
...
<Route exact path='/dashboard/' component={Index} />
            <Route path='/dashboard/login' component={Index} />
            <Route path='/dashboard/cartable' component={Index} />
            <Route path='/dashboard/cartable/requests' component={Index} />
            <Route path='/dashboard/cartable/approved' component={Index} />
            <Route path='/dashboard/cartable/rejected' component={Index} />
            <Route path='/dashboard/elections-management' component={Index} />
            <Route path='/dashboard/statistics' component={Index} />
            <Route path='/dashboard/statistics/assignee' component={Index} />
            <Route path='/dashboard/statistics/participation' component={Index} />
            <Route path='/dashboard/statistics/candidate-report' component={Index} />
            <Route path='/dashboard/change-pass' component={Index} />
            <Route path='/dashboard/errors' component={Index} />
...
```

in my index.js :

```js
...
<Route exact path='/dashboard/' component={Layout} />
            <Route exact path='/dashboard/cartable' component={Layout} />
            <Route path='/dashboard/cartable/requests' component={Layout} />
            <Route path='/dashboard/cartable/approved' component={Layout} />
            <Route path='/dashboard/cartable/rejected' component={Layout} />
            <Route path='/dashboard/elections-management' component={Layout} />
            <Route exact path='/dashboard/statistics' component={Layout} />
            <Route path='/dashboard/statistics/assignee' component={Layout} />
            <Route path='/dashboard/statistics/participation' component={Layout} />
            <Route path='/dashboard/statistics/candidate-report' component={Layout} />
            <Route path='/dashboard/change-pass' component={Layout} />
            <Route path='/dashboard/errors' component={Layout} />
...
```

in my layout.js :

```js
...
<Route exact path='/dashboard' component={Requests} />
                                <Route exact path='/dashboard/cartable' component={Requests} />
                                <Route path='/dashboard/cartable/requests' component={Requests} />
                                <Route path='/dashboard/cartable/approved' component={Approved} />
                                <Route path='/dashboard/cartable/rejected' component={Rejected} />
                                <Route path='/dashboard/elections-management' component={ElectionManagement} />
                                <Route exact path='/dashboard/statistics' component={Participation} />
                                <Route path='/dashboard/statistics/assignee' component={Assignee} />
                                <Route path='/dashboard/statistics/participation' component={Participation} />
                                <Route path='/dashboard/statistics/candidate-report' component={CandidateReport} />
                                <Route path='/dashboard/change-pass' component={ChangePassword} />
                                <Route path='/dashboard/errors' component={Errors} />
...
```

Comment: you should add exact params in your route path. The exact param comes into play when you have multiple paths that have similar names

Comment: Can you put your sample code into codepen or any sandbox

Answer (score 0):

I believe that could get fixed if you move the "/dashboard" route to the end of the list

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your Route by Switch like this

```
<Switch>
   <Route
   ...

</Switch>
```